# HTTPModule filter questions

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I have one issues I'm struggling with with regards to my HTTPModule filter:

1) I notice that the module gets it's data in chunks. This is problematic for me because I'm using a regex to find and replace. If I get a partial match in one chunk and the rest of the match in the second, it will not work. Is there any way to get the entire response before I do my thing to it? I have seen code where it appends data to a string builder until it uses a matches on an "" end tag but my code must work for more that just  (xml, custom tags, etc). I don't know how to detect the End Of Stream or if that is even possible.

I am attaching the filter in the BeginRequest.

Comment: why do you need a http module for that, is it something that could be handled in a subclassed page with overriden Load event? 
modules are useful if you want to cover all .net resources (and non .net as well), but this may be just a page operation?

Comment: No it is for a site wide regex replacement feature. Bascially it needs to process all html, xml, json, soap, anything that may contain text data. There are many examples here but they are all set to recognize a closing tag as the psuedo end of stream marker. I'd like mine to be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters). It looks for "" in the stream of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample project which performs buffered search and replace in an HttpModule using a Request.Filter and Response.Filter.  You should be able to adapt this technique to perform a Regex easily.

https://github.com/snives/HttpModuleRewrite